# How do you use a background-image for a DIV along with a double line border so that the image doesn't show through the border?

Tags: css, border

I have a DIV where I've put a background-image. I also have a border to the DIV using a double line. You can see the image between the lines. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Please provide some code, what you have tried already, specific browser info, any detail that can help us help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I haven't tried anything because my general internet searches didn't turn up any solutions.

My code is:
    <div class="Header_Section_Left" style="background-image: url( '<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>');">

This is being done in Wordpress, so it's currently inline CSS until I figure out the solution and then I can move it to the CSS document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent it with `background-clip: padding-box`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Comment: I responded before checking that I had my code correct. I had left out the semi-colon. So, it was indeed the correct answer to my problem.

I didn't provide code for it because it seemed like a simple question with an obviously simple answer that I clearly hadn't thought of. You can search the internet all you like, but you can't always find the answer you're looking for when you're looking for it.

Comment: @OscarGuy: Ah, good. I wasn't mistaken about your question being straightforward then. And that's why I'm happy to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it was an easy solution. I learned CSS several years ago and don't recall ever seeing background-clip, so that one was a new one on me.

Comment: @OscarGuy: background-clip is a CSS3 property that's only been around since 2010-ish. Which is quite a bit of time now that I think about it, but it's also one of the obscure ones. Among the CSS3 background properties the most commonly used one by far is background-size.